# how to customize the alfresco explorer footer text

Tags: alfresco

how to customize alfresco explorer footer text.we are using 4.2 enterprise version.When I search the forums that we need to change the PageTag.java file.
as we have enterprise  lincense,how do we get this file?do i need to take from the existing jar(alfresc-web-client) file?

Comment: Ask your commercial Enterprise support. That's what you pay them for :)

Comment: As an enterprise customer, you can get access to the enterprise part of the source tree. As Lutz says, talk to support, that's what you pay for!

Comment: I got the file. how to place this class so that it override the existing PageTag class that exists in alfresco-webclient.jar.

Answer (score 0):

Rather then changing original **PageTag.java**. Override that and create your own class. Then replace all references of PageTag from context file with your new class name.

I had done that earlier but I could not recollect those file names and references. But, that is certainly way to go rather then changing core class.